# Who commanded the Republic Navy at the beginning of the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars

Simply put, who commanded the ships at the Battle of Geonosis?  Is there a canon mention of Jedi leading the ships, or were there volunteers from member worlds?

Comment: fyi the republic did have a standing army with non clone officers

Comment: I know of the Judicials, but were they enough to form the officers for the entire GAR?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the book "The Clone Wars: Wild Space", Yoda initiates the effort to bring the clone army to Geonosis, but also talks with Admiral [Wullf Yularen](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wullf_Yularen) during and after the main fight. When Yoda is called back to Coruscant, he leaves Yularen in charge of the remaining operations. It's safe to assume that the Republic is most likely employing the same tactic as we see so often in Clone Wars show; that is, Yularen commands the space fleet, while a Jedi (in this case, Yoda) takes care of the ground operations.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for the Battle of Geonosis, you could make the argument that it was Yoda, since he was the one to bring the clones from Kamino.